# Counting records in JSON result using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, json

Completely new to most of this stuff, but basically Im playing around with the Facebook API on a rainy Saturday afernoon for a bit of a challenge.

I've taken the code at the bottom of this page:-

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

And changed it around a little.  Basically what I'm trying to do at this point is just to print up on screen the total number of friends, which I assume is as easy as returning the number of records returned by the JSON query, but I can't get it right.  I know I'm doing something wrong but need a pointer as to what.  At the moment my code only returns 1, where it should be 160 or so.

My code is here (I've taken out my app id/secret):-

```
    <?php

  //Very basic code to pull out details about the logged in user.
  $app_id = 'myid';
  $app_secret = 'mysecret';
  $my_url = 'http://lab.2toria.com/facebook/test1.php';

  $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

 //auth user
 if(empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' 
    . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) ;
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
  }

  //get user access_token
  $token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='
    . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) 
    . '&client_secret=' . $app_secret 
    . '&code=' . $code;
  $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  // Run fql query
  $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . '/fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()'
    . '&' . $access_token;
  $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
  $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);

  //Now need to find a way to count the number of results returned in the array to get the number of facebook friends.
  for($a=0;$a<count($fql_query_obj);$a++)
  {
    $theCount++;  
  }

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r("Number of friends:");
  print_r($theCount);
  echo '</pre>';


?>
```

Thanks in advance.
Mat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this

> for($a=0;$a<count($fql_query_obj['data']);$a++)

as Facebook response will have a data property which contains the original data.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure, but couldn't you just print the `count($fql_query_obj)` since it is an array now this should return the same value,shouldn't it?

EDIT: and have you checked if facebook is givin you a valid json_object back?

Comment: Yes, it definitely is returning a valid object as I can change the output to show the full list of users.  I'll have a quick test using your suggestion.

Comment: can you post the content of the returned object (or the array you are creating with json_encode)